# Injecting A Proxied Dependency Into A Property Typed To An Implementation In Spring Batch

Tags: spring, interface, dependency-injection, type-conversion, spring-batch

The crux of my problem is how to type a property to expose the methods from two different interfaces, when the property will be injected with a Spring Batch proxy.

My design problem is concerning how to inject a dependency that Spring has proxied for use in Spring Batch. The dependency is proxied by Spring because it has been scoped to the Spring Batch step. This is required because the dependency has values that must be injected from the Spring Batch Job Parameters. Scoping the bean to the Spring Batch step is the best way to make the dependency available in the ExecutionContext so that the Job Parameters can be injected. Any input in how to resolve this would be very much appreciated.

My specific situation is in implementing an AggregateItemReader in Spring Batch as explained in the [Spring Batch Samples](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/spring-batch-samples/). You can find a the source for the example AggregateItemReader [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-samples/1.1.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline/AggregateItemReader.java) and the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/spring-batch-samples/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline/AggregateItemReader.html).

The difference is my implementation intends to use the JdbcCursorItemReader to aggregate from. This means that my AggregateItemReader must implement the interfaces ItemReader and ItemStream. This allows my AggregateItemReader to be used properly by Spring Batch by exposing the open(ExecutionContext executionContext), update(ExecutionContext executionContext), and close() methods needed by Spring Batch to manage the ItemStream. In addition, the property in my AggregateItemReader that stores a reference to the ItemReader that handles the data loading must provide access to these same methods. So the property is typed to the JdbcCursorItemReader. This introduces a problem as the proxy Spring Batch creates is baed on the dependency's interfaces, ItemReader and ItemStream. A proxy of these types can't be injected into a property typed to JdbcCursorItemReader.

Comment: Do you need to access specific methods of `JdbcCursorItemReader` in your aggregate reader?

Comment: I need to access the read(), open(ExecutionContext executionContext), update(ExecutionContext executionContext), and close() of the JdbcCursorItemReader.

Comment: so inject a `ItemReader<T>` property and cast to `ItemStream` when request in your code

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to find a way without casting. But if I must, I must.

Comment: cast to ItemStream when requested (in AggregateReader: open(), update() and close()) is not "bad", but the right way to proceed: also you can register injected JdbcCursorItemReader as stream to let spring-batch save execution context